# ICC using linear models

Tags: model, linear, intraclass-correlation

I am using a linear model to calculate the ICC in a repeated measures dataset in order to get an estimate of the reliability of my measurement. 
The model I am currently using looks like this

`mod = lmer(x ~ (1|subj), data = test_data`

with a resulting ICC calculated by

$\frac{RE}{RE + res}$

I now want to include another effect, namely number of years after disease onset, to see whether the reliability changes with varying years. Do I need to include the years as an interaction term? And how would I then calculate the years-dependent ICC?